# How do I need to alter a recipe if I am using a convection oven?

Tags: baking, temperature, oven, convection

How do I need to alter a recipe if I am using a convection oven as if a recipe calls to use a regular oven? Do I need to alter the recipe or there would only be the differences of baking time/temperature.

Comment: Can't you just turn  convection off? Also, what recipe is it?

Comment: See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3916/67

Comment: @Mołot certainly not every fan oven has the option to turn it off. My cooker has two ovens, a small conventional and the main fan oven. If I’m baking something of any great depth, a loaf of a cake it *has* to go in the fan oven and the fan cannot be turned off independently.